# Postgresql : I want to insert data some way like below -

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like below -

```
id  someId  someType    someEmailId
-------------------------------------
1       {1}     someType        someEmailId
1       {2,3,4}     someType2       someEmailId2
```

Now, I want to have unique entries in this table based on unique combination of someId, someType, someEmailId column.
Also, I want to make sure if someone does a new entry using an insert statement with data like -

```
id  someId  someType    someEmailId
-----------------------------------------------------
200     {2}   someType2     someEmailId2
```

then this should also be not allowed since the someId column(of array type) already contains the element 2 and other fields(someType and someEmailId) are also same for the entry.

I am keeping a unique key constraint on table with columns (someId, someType, someEmailId), but not sure how I can stop the insert case I mentioned.
I know I can do it someway with @> operator.

Comment: one more insert case - 
```
400              {2,3}           someType2             someEmailId2
```
This should also not be possible.

Comment: I guess a unique constraint cannot give you this check. You could write a trigger to perform the check on the array entries

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an [EXCLUDE constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION).

But to use one, you will need to create some extensions which create the correct operator families:

```
create extension btree_gist;
create extension intarray;
alter table sometable add constraint dfaf exclude using gist (sometype with =, someemailid with =, someid with &&);
```

(I'm not terribly fond of the 'intarray' module, but don't know of a better way to get this functionality)

With this in place, then if you try the insert you indicated:

```
insert into sometable values (200, '{2}', 'someType2', 'someEmailId2');
```

You will get a constraint violation because there is already a row which is = on sometype and somemailid and which overlaps (&&) on someid, so will get an ERROR and message like this:

```
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "dfaf"
DETAIL:  Key (sometype, someemailid, someid)=(someType2, someEmailId2, {2}) conflicts with existing key (sometype, someemailid, someid)=(someType2, someEmailId2, {2,3,4}).
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Can you please elaborate a bit on how the case of insert attempts like - 
 400    {2,3} someType2     someEmailId2
 200     {2}   someType2     someEmailId2
would be stopped? Not the quickest learner. :)